# How to format the output of the date-object (not as string)?

Tags: java, android, android-date

I'm trying to pass a Date-Object to a SOAP-API and need the output of the date-object itself to be `yyyy-MM-dd`

I'm already converting my string into a date-object like this:

```
// String __startDatum = "2013-02-05";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(__startDatum);
```

For now the output of `convertedDate` will be `Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2013`.

How could I change the output of `convertedDate` to be `2013-02-05`? 
Please keep in mind I still need it to be a date-object not a string!

Comment: Might help to find out what you actually need, if you would tell what you are calling in the soap-API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For now the output of convertedDate will be Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2013.

There's no "output of `convertedDate`" - it's *just* a `Date` variable. The only way to get "Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2013" would be to call `toString()` on it, either implicitly or explicitly - and you can't change the format used by `Date.toString()`.

It's important to understand that a `Date` is *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It doesn't have a time zone; it doesn't have a calendar system; it doesn't have a particular format.

If you want a better API which allows you to create an object which *just* represents a date (rather than a date/time) you should look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a far nicer date and time API than the built-in one. It's reasonably large - primarily due to the time zone data, I believe - so you may want to look for a cut down version tailored to Android. It's mostly a pleasure to work with though - at least compared with `Date` and `Calendar`.